# An upper bound for the number of singularities of a transversal vector field isometric to the zero field

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. We  equip the tangent bundle $TM$ with the Sasaki metric $g_s$.

A smooth vector field $X:M \to TM$ is called a transversal vector field if $X(M)$ is transverse to the zero section. We say that a vector field $X$ is "Isometric to the zero field" if there is an isometry $\phi$ of $(TM,g_s)$ which maps $X(M)$ to the zero section.

> Question:Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. Is there a uniform upper bound $N$, depending  only on $(M,g)$, such that every transversal vector field $X$ isometric to the zero field has at most $N$ singularities?

We  denote by $n_0$, the  infimum of all $N$ with the above property. This $n_0$ is  a geometric  invariant  associated  to the Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$.

> If the  answer  of the  main  question is  not  affirmative, what  about if we merely consider the  space  of real  analytic  vector  fields, rather than the  wider class of  all  smooth vector fields?

Comment: Do you assume that $M$ is compact? Also, are you aware of any example of a compact manifold $M$ such that isometries of $TM$ with Sasaki metric don't preserve the structure of a fibration?

Comment: @DmitriPanov  I  am  really sorry  for  my  delay.  Yes  I  assume  M  is  compact. Regarding  your  second question, if  I  understand it correctly, I  guess that such  an  example  exist. When  M  is not compact, say $M=\mathbb{R}$. there are isometries  of $T\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^2$  which  does  not  preserves  the  fiber  structure, the  rotations  of  the  plane. So  I think that  one  can  construct a  similar example  for  cylinder the  tangent  bundle  of  the  circle.